# Uncaught TypeError: uniqueNames[name_1].push is not a function

Tags: solidity

[image]I'm getting this error while deploying smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.7.5;

import "./libraries/SafeMath.sol";
// import "./libraries/SafeERC20.sol";

import "./interfaces/IOwnable.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import "./interfaces/IOHM.sol";
import "./interfaces/IsOHM.sol";
import "./interfaces/IBondingCalculator.sol";
import "./interfaces/ITreasury.sol";

import "./types/OlympusAccessControlled.sol";

interface IERC20Mintable {
  function mint( uint256 amount_ ) external;

  function mint( address account_, uint256 ammount_ ) external;
}

contract OKPTreasury is OlympusAccessControlled {

using SafeMath for uint;
// using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

event Deposit( address indexed token, uint amount, uint value );
event Withdrawal( address indexed token, uint amount, uint value );
event CreateDebt( address indexed debtor, address indexed token, uint amount, uint value );
event RepayDebt( address indexed debtor, address indexed token, uint amount, uint value );
event ReservesManaged( address indexed token, uint amount );
event ReservesUpdated( uint indexed totalReserves );
event ReservesAudited( uint indexed totalReserves );
event RewardsMinted( address indexed caller, address indexed recipient, uint amount );
event ChangeQueued( MANAGING indexed managing, address queued );
event ChangeActivated( MANAGING indexed managing, address activated, bool result );

enum MANAGING { RESERVEDEPOSITOR, RESERVESPENDER, RESERVETOKEN, RESERVEMANAGER, LIQUIDITYDEPOSITOR, LIQUIDITYTOKEN, LIQUIDITYMANAGER, DEBTOR, REWARDMANAGER, SOKP }

address public immutable OKP;
uint public blocksNeededForQueue;

address[] public reserveTokens; // Push only, beware false-positives.
mapping( address => bool ) public isReserveToken;
mapping( address => uint ) public reserveTokenQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public reserveDepositors; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isReserveDepositor;
mapping( address => uint ) public reserveDepositorQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public reserveSpenders; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isReserveSpender;
mapping( address => uint ) public reserveSpenderQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public liquidityTokens; // Push only, beware false-positives.
mapping( address => bool ) public isLiquidityToken;
mapping( address => uint ) public LiquidityTokenQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public liquidityDepositors; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isLiquidityDepositor;
mapping( address => uint ) public LiquidityDepositorQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

mapping( address => address ) public bondCalculator; // bond calculator for liquidity token

address[] public reserveManagers; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isReserveManager;
mapping( address => uint ) public ReserveManagerQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public liquidityManagers; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isLiquidityManager;
mapping( address => uint ) public LiquidityManagerQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address[] public debtors; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isDebtor;
mapping( address => uint ) public debtorQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.
mapping( address => uint ) public debtorBalance;

address[] public rewardManagers; // Push only, beware false-positives. Only for viewing.
mapping( address => bool ) public isRewardManager;
mapping( address => uint ) public rewardManagerQueue; // Delays changes to mapping.

address public sOKP;
uint public sOKPQueue; // Delays change to sOKP address

uint public totalReserves; // Risk-free value of all assets
uint public totalDebt;

constructor (
    address _OKP,
    address _BUSD,
    address _authority,
    uint _blocksNeededForQueue
) OlympusAccessControlled(IOlympusAuthority(_authority)) {
    require( _OKP != address(0) );
    OKP = _OKP;

    isReserveToken[ _BUSD ] = true;
    reserveTokens.push( _BUSD );

    blocksNeededForQueue = _blocksNeededForQueue;
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to deposit an asset for OKP
    @param _amount uint
    @param _token address
    @param _profit uint
    @return send_ uint
 */
function deposit( uint _amount, address _token, uint _profit ) external returns ( uint send_ ) {
    require( isReserveToken[ _token ] || isLiquidityToken[ _token ], "Not accepted" );
    IERC20( _token ).transferFrom( msg.sender, address(this), _amount );

    if ( isReserveToken[ _token ] ) {
        require( isReserveDepositor[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    } else {
        require( isLiquidityDepositor[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    }

    uint value = valueOf(_token, _amount);
    // mint OKP needed and store amount of rewards for distribution
    // s = 100000000000 - 99909426854 = 0.090573146
    send_ = value.sub( _profit );
    IERC20Mintable( OKP ).mint( msg.sender, send_ );

    totalReserves = totalReserves.add( value );
    emit ReservesUpdated( totalReserves );

    emit Deposit( _token, _amount, value );
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to burn OKP for reserves
    @param _amount uint
    @param _token address
 */
function withdraw( uint _amount, address _token ) external {
    require( isReserveToken[ _token ], "Not accepted" ); // Only reserves can be used for redemptions
    require( isReserveSpender[ msg.sender ] == true, "Not approved" );

    uint value = valueOf( _token, _amount );
    IOHM( OKP ).burnFrom( msg.sender, value );

    totalReserves = totalReserves.sub( value );
    emit ReservesUpdated( totalReserves );

    IERC20( _token ).transfer( msg.sender, _amount );

    emit Withdrawal( _token, _amount, value );
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to borrow reserves
    @param _amount uint
    @param _token address
 */
function incurDebt( uint _amount, address _token ) external {
    require( isDebtor[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    require( isReserveToken[ _token ], "Not accepted" );

    uint value = valueOf( _token, _amount );

    uint maximumDebt = IERC20( sOKP ).balanceOf( msg.sender ); // Can only borrow against sOKP held
    uint availableDebt = maximumDebt.sub( debtorBalance[ msg.sender ] );
    require( value <= availableDebt, "Exceeds debt limit" );

    debtorBalance[ msg.sender ] = debtorBalance[ msg.sender ].add( value );
    totalDebt = totalDebt.add( value );

    totalReserves = totalReserves.sub( value );
    emit ReservesUpdated( totalReserves );

    IERC20( _token ).transfer( msg.sender, _amount );
    
    emit CreateDebt( msg.sender, _token, _amount, value );
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to repay borrowed reserves with reserves
    @param _amount uint
    @param _token address
 */
function repayDebtWithReserve( uint _amount, address _token ) external {
    require( isDebtor[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    require( isReserveToken[ _token ], "Not accepted" );

    IERC20( _token ).transferFrom( msg.sender, address(this), _amount );

    uint value = valueOf( _token, _amount );
    debtorBalance[ msg.sender ] = debtorBalance[ msg.sender ].sub( value );
    totalDebt = totalDebt.sub( value );

    totalReserves = totalReserves.add( value );
    emit ReservesUpdated( totalReserves );

    emit RepayDebt( msg.sender, _token, _amount, value );
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to repay borrowed reserves with OKP
    @param _amount uint
 */
function repayDebtWithOKP( uint _amount ) external {
    require( isDebtor[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );

    IOHM( OKP ).burnFrom( msg.sender, _amount );

    debtorBalance[ msg.sender ] = debtorBalance[ msg.sender ].sub( _amount );
    totalDebt = totalDebt.sub( _amount );

    emit RepayDebt( msg.sender, OKP, _amount, _amount );
}

/**
    @notice allow approved address to withdraw assets
    @param _token address
    @param _amount uint
 */
function manage( address _token, uint _amount ) external {
    if( isLiquidityToken[ _token ] ) {
        require( isLiquidityManager[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    } else {
        require( isReserveManager[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    }

    uint value = valueOf(_token, _amount);
    require( value <= excessReserves(), "Insufficient reserves" );

    totalReserves = totalReserves.sub( value );
    emit ReservesUpdated( totalReserves );

    IERC20( _token ).transfer( msg.sender, _amount );

    emit ReservesManaged( _token, _amount );
}

/**
    @notice send epoch reward to staking contract
 */
function mintRewards( address _recipient, uint _amount ) external {
    require( isRewardManager[ msg.sender ], "Not approved" );
    require( _amount <= excessReserves(), "Insufficient reserves" );

    IERC20Mintable( OKP ).mint( _recipient, _amount );

    emit RewardsMinted( msg.sender, _recipient, _amount );
} 

/**
    @notice returns excess reserves not backing tokens
    @return uint
 */
function excessReserves() public view returns ( uint ) {
    return totalReserves.sub( IERC20( OKP ).totalSupply().sub( totalDebt ) );
}

/**
    @notice takes inventory of all tracked assets
    @notice always consolidate to recognized reserves before audit
 */
function auditReserves() external onlyGovernor() {
    uint reserves;
    for( uint i = 0; i < reserveTokens.length; i++ ) {
        reserves = reserves.add (
            valueOf( reserveTokens[ i ], IERC20( reserveTokens[ i ] ).balanceOf( address(this) ) )
        );
    }
    for( uint i = 0; i < liquidityTokens.length; i++ ) {
        reserves = reserves.add (
            valueOf( liquidityTokens[ i ], IERC20( liquidityTokens[ i ] ).balanceOf( address(this) ) )
        );
    }
    totalReserves = reserves;
    emit ReservesUpdated( reserves );
    emit ReservesAudited( reserves );
}

/**
    @notice returns OKP valuation of asset
    @param _token address
    @param _amount uint
    @return value_ uint
 */
function valueOf( address _token, uint _amount ) public view returns ( uint value_ ) {
    if ( isReserveToken[ _token ] ) {
        // convert amount to match OKP decimals
        value_ = _amount.mul( 10 ** IERC20Metadata( OKP ).decimals() ).div( 10 ** IERC20Metadata( _token ).decimals() );
    } else if ( isLiquidityToken[ _token ] ) {
        value_ = IBondingCalculator( bondCalculator[ _token ] ).valuation( _token, _amount );
    }
}

function setNeededQueueBlock(uint _blocksNeededForQueue) public onlyGovernor() {
    blocksNeededForQueue = _blocksNeededForQueue;
}
/**
    @notice queue address to change boolean in mapping
    @param _managing MANAGING
    @param _address address
    @return bool
 */
function queue( MANAGING _managing, address _address ) external onlyGovernor() returns ( bool ) {
    require( _address != address(0) );
    if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVEDEPOSITOR ) { // 0
        reserveDepositorQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVESPENDER ) { // 1
        reserveSpenderQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVETOKEN ) { // 2
        reserveTokenQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVEMANAGER ) { // 3
        ReserveManagerQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue.mul( 2 ) );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYDEPOSITOR ) { // 4
        LiquidityDepositorQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYTOKEN ) { // 5
        LiquidityTokenQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYMANAGER ) { // 6
        LiquidityManagerQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue.mul( 2 ) );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.DEBTOR ) { // 7
        debtorQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.REWARDMANAGER ) { // 8
        rewardManagerQueue[ _address ] = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.SOKP ) { // 9
        sOKPQueue = block.number.add( blocksNeededForQueue );
    } else return false;

    emit ChangeQueued( _managing, _address );
    return true;
}

/**
    @notice verify queue then set boolean in mapping
    @param _managing MANAGING
    @param _address address
    @param _calculator address
    @return bool
 */
function toggle( MANAGING _managing, address _address, address _calculator ) external onlyGovernor() returns ( bool ) {
    require( _address != address(0) );
    bool result;
    if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVEDEPOSITOR ) { // 0
        if ( requirements( reserveDepositorQueue, isReserveDepositor, _address ) ) {
            reserveDepositorQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( reserveDepositors, _address ) ) {
                reserveDepositors.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isReserveDepositor[ _address ];
        isReserveDepositor[ _address ] = result;
        
    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVESPENDER ) { // 1
        if ( requirements( reserveSpenderQueue, isReserveSpender, _address ) ) {
            reserveSpenderQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( reserveSpenders, _address ) ) {
                reserveSpenders.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isReserveSpender[ _address ];
        isReserveSpender[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVETOKEN ) { // 2
        if ( requirements( reserveTokenQueue, isReserveToken, _address ) ) {
            reserveTokenQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( reserveTokens, _address ) ) {
                reserveTokens.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isReserveToken[ _address ];
        isReserveToken[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.RESERVEMANAGER ) { // 3
        if ( requirements( ReserveManagerQueue, isReserveManager, _address ) ) {
            reserveManagers.push( _address );
            ReserveManagerQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( reserveManagers, _address ) ) {
                reserveManagers.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isReserveManager[ _address ];
        isReserveManager[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYDEPOSITOR ) { // 4
        if ( requirements( LiquidityDepositorQueue, isLiquidityDepositor, _address ) ) {
            liquidityDepositors.push( _address );
            LiquidityDepositorQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( liquidityDepositors, _address ) ) {
                liquidityDepositors.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isLiquidityDepositor[ _address ];
        isLiquidityDepositor[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYTOKEN ) { // 5
        if ( requirements( LiquidityTokenQueue, isLiquidityToken, _address ) ) {
            LiquidityTokenQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( liquidityTokens, _address ) ) {
                liquidityTokens.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isLiquidityToken[ _address ];
        isLiquidityToken[ _address ] = result;
        bondCalculator[ _address ] = _calculator;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.LIQUIDITYMANAGER ) { // 6
        if ( requirements( LiquidityManagerQueue, isLiquidityManager, _address ) ) {
            LiquidityManagerQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( liquidityManagers, _address ) ) {
                liquidityManagers.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isLiquidityManager[ _address ];
        isLiquidityManager[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.DEBTOR ) { // 7
        if ( requirements( debtorQueue, isDebtor, _address ) ) {
            debtorQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( debtors, _address ) ) {
                debtors.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isDebtor[ _address ];
        isDebtor[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.REWARDMANAGER ) { // 8
        if ( requirements( rewardManagerQueue, isRewardManager, _address ) ) {
            rewardManagerQueue[ _address ] = 0;
            if( !listContains( rewardManagers, _address ) ) {
                rewardManagers.push( _address );
            }
        }
        result = !isRewardManager[ _address ];
        isRewardManager[ _address ] = result;

    } else if ( _managing == MANAGING.SOKP ) { // 9
        sOKPQueue = 0;
        sOKP = _address;
        result = true;

    } else return false;

    emit ChangeActivated( _managing, _address, result );
    return true;
}

/**
    @notice checks requirements and returns altered structs
    @param queue_ mapping( address => uint )
    @param status_ mapping( address => bool )
    @param _address address
    @return bool 
 */
function requirements( 
    mapping( address => uint ) storage queue_, 
    mapping( address => bool ) storage status_, 
    address _address 
) internal view returns ( bool ) {
    if ( !status_[ _address ] ) {
        require( queue_[ _address ] != 0, "Must queue" );
        require( queue_[ _address ] <= block.number, "Queue not expired" );
        return true;
    } return false;
}

/**
    @notice checks array to ensure against duplicate
    @param _list address[]
    @param _token address
    @return bool
 */
function listContains( address[] storage _list, address _token ) internal view returns ( bool ) {
    for( uint i = 0; i < _list.length; i++ ) {
        if( _list[ i ] == _token ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think the error occurs in this file. I think you are getting in conflicts with built in js functions while testing. It would be helpful if you upload your test files.

Comment: but I'm not calling test file

Comment: or your deployment script